# Do getchar() and putchar() read only one character each time they're called or do they read a stream of characters?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, getchar, putchar

There is something vague about the functionality of `getchar()`, `putchar()` in while loop for me.
In the following program that copies its input to its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

1- how does `getchar()` store its value in c? If `getchar()` reads the next input character each time it's called, then if we input "Hello world", only "H" should be stored in `c` since `getchar()` was called only once before the while loop.
however If `getchar()` reads a *stream of characters*, then how is the value stored in a variable such as c which is not an array?

2- kind of the same question about `putchar()`. how does `putchar()` output a *stream of characters* if it only prints the next character each time it is called? in the while loop it should print only one character and then go to the next line and wait for the next character input. The while loop doesn't just execute the `putchar(c)` statement repeatedly to print the whole string. it loops over the whole block, right?

I think my consideration is that the program should read one character from input, go inside the while loop, print out the character if it's not EOF and wait for the next input. I don't understand how it prints a stream of characters...

Comment: The `while` loop *does* execute the `c = getchar();` and `putchar(c);` statement repeatedly to print the whole string. `getchar()` won't store its value to `c`. It is a task for the assignment operator `=` executed *after* `getchar()` returns.

Comment: `getchar()` reads one character, but it might not return with the first one until Enter has been pressed, when input is buffered. Then, it will also read Enter. Similarly, the character output by `putchar()` might not appear on the console until the output buffer is flushed (by newline, by being full, by the program ending, or by `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand an important concept about streams. Multiple characters are being received and are ready for reading instantly. The "wait" would only happen if the input buffer is being fed very slowly. In fact the `getchar` call is blocking and waiting for the next character, but in your situation it probably returns immediately. Buffering and caching can be confusing concepts.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` reads one character and `putchar` writes one character.

A `while` loop keeps running the whole block until the "condition" part (`c != EOF`) isn't true, then it moves on to the next statement after the block, like usual.

This is a very basic property of loops (all of them, not just `while`). If you got past loops in your textbook or tutorial you might want to go back and study them some more.

Your program reads one character, writes it, reads one, writes it, reads one, writes it, ..... until it reads EOF instead of a character.

Comment: When it reaches the end of the file, `getchar()` will return EOF.  It will never "read" it.